# gdevilspie not working

Tags: 16.04, gdevilspie

I'd like to always open the gedit application in workspace 3.

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and gedevilspie

How can I get the following simple code to work?

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/.devilspie$ cat text.ds 
; generated_rule text
( if 
( begin 
( is ( application_name ) "gedit" )
) 
( begin 
( set_workspace 3 )
( println "match" )
)
)
```

Current Configuration

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/.devilspie$ cat text.ds 
; generated_rule text
( if 
( begin 
( is ( application_name ) "gedit" )
) 
( begin 
( set_viewport 3 )
( println "match" )
)
)
```

Comment: do you have `compiz` on your machine?

Comment: My synaptic shows compiz , compiz-core, compiz-gnome,  compiz-plugins, compiz-plugins-default as INSTALLED.  If you suggest me to un-install compiz, do i get impact on my cairo-dock and what other impact I will have

Answer (score 0):

Specify viewport instead of workspace.

```
( if 
( begin 
( is ( application_name ) "gedit" )
) 
( begin 
( set_viewport 3 )
( println "match" )
)
)
```

Comment: Attempted not working.

Comment: @Dinesh Let's kill it, restart, and launch gedit: `killall devilspie && devilspie & gedit`

You should see the word 'match' in the terminal after gedit is launched.

Comment: Executed from worspace 1, expecting gedit to open at workspace 3.  Terminal displays match but gedit opens in the workspace 1. dinesh@ubuntu:~$ killall devilspie && devilspie & gedit
[1] 1145
match

Comment: Hmm. Working for me. Would you mind posting text.ds again, just to be sure?

Comment: Sometime back it did not work, now its working. Not sure about the stability, let me watch for sometime, then i need to add few more applications.

Comment: @Dinesh Is this resolved?

Comment: it is not stable and erratic.